# TFS 2013 - Link Work Items via Spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have an Excel worksheet with hundreds of TFS 2013 Work Item IDs populating both Column A and Column B. For illustrative purposes, let's just say I have the following:

Row 1 to Row 100 of Column A: Populated with the Work Item IDs of 100 Bug Work Items

Row 1 - Row 100 of Column B populated with the Work Item IDs of 100 Task Work Items.

What I'd like to do is have an automated process, e.g. a script that iterates through the hundred rows of my Excel spreadsheet and link the work item IDs in Column A with the corresponding work item IDs in Column B on the same row, e.g. link the work items listed in A1 to that of B1, A2 to B2, A3 to B3, etc.

I can for instance see a For loop achieving such a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you save the spreadsheet as a .csv file and have two columns with headings Parent and Child then using this excellent blog post as inspiration:

http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/bulk-migrate-work-item-comments-links-and-attachments

Try this:

```
$tpcUrl = "http://myserver:8080/tfs/MyCollection"
$csvFile = ".\map.csv" #format: Parent, Child

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common')
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client')
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client')

$tpc = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tpcUrl)
$wis = $tpc.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])

$list = Import-Csv $csvFile

foreach($map in $list) 
{
   $childWIT = $wis.GetWorkItem($map.Child)

   Write-Host "Creating Link from Parent:$($map.Parent) to Child:$($map.Child)" -ForegroundColor Green

   $hierarchyLink = $wis.WorkItemLinkTypes[[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.CoreLinkTypeReferenceNames]::Hierarchy]
   $link = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemLink($hierarchyLink.ReverseEnd, $map.Parent)    
   $childWIT.WorkItemLinks.Add($link)
   try 
   {
      $childWIT.Save();
      Write-Host "Link created" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
   }
   catch 
   {
      Write-Error "Could not save work item $map.Child"
      Write-Error $_
   }
}

Write-Host
Write-Host "Linking complete"
```

Comment: rerwinRR, you're an absolute genius!! Thank you. Thank you. I will give it a go asap. I take it this should work for other work item link types too aside Parent-Child? My requirement is simply to create Related links between the two work item types you see.

Comment: sure, you can just change the link type to related                                      $hierarchyLink = $wis.WorkItemLinkTypes[[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.CoreLinkTypeReferenceNames]::Related]

Comment: Hi rerwinRR, as a reverse activity, how would I remove in bulk the added work item links please? I would like to believe this very same script for creating the links could simply be modified to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Even easier, run a tree query or direct links query which displays the links you want to delete.  Select the child items and hit the outdent (should that be unindent?) button. Publish the sheet and links should be removed with no need for scripts