# How to import linked Test Cases/User Stories from Excel into TFS2013?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have a set of User stories and their associated test cases in an Excel spreadsheet. I set it up as a tree list as per this page here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286627.aspx), but when I import into TFS 2013 the test cases only show up under the "All Links" tab, not the "Test Cases" tab.

How do I import User Stories and their associated test cases from Excel and have the test cases appear under "Test Cases", and likewise have the User Stories linked under "Tested User Stories" tab on the test cases?

Comment: Excel will create Parent-Child links and you'd like Tests-Tested by links so you're looking at using the TFS API.  I'd pull the IDs into a csv file and then use a PowerShell script to create the links.  If you haven't got that many and it's a one-off thing then obviously you could do it manually but that's no fun.

Comment: @rerwinRR Thanks. Any guidance on how to do this with PowerShell? That is beyond anything I've tried before.

Comment: I thought this was familiar :-)  This was a similar question I answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335878/tfs-2013-link-work-items-via-spreadsheet/30347721#30347721  The difference here would be to change the link type to TestedBy.  More detail on link types here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/02/27/tfs-api-part-22-create-link-between-work-item-parent-child-etc/

Comment: @rerwinRR awesome, thanks! If you want to put this in as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel will create Parent-Child links and you'd like Tests-Tested by links so you're looking at using the TFS API.

I'd pull the IDs into a csv file and then use a PowerShell script to create the links.

This was a similar question I answered with more details on the script:

[TFS 2013 - Link Work Items via Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335878/tfs-2013-link-work-items-via-spreadsheet/30347721#30347721)

The easiest thing would be to have two columns, one for User Story ID and one for Test Case ID.  You'd just repeat the Story ID in multiple rows if it has more than one Test Case.

The only difference here would be to change the link type to TestedBy rather than Hierarchy.

More detail on link types here:

[TFS API Part 22 – Create Link Between Work Item](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/02/27/tfs-api-part-22-create-link-between-work-item-parent-child-etc/)