# TFS 2013 - Link Work Items via Spreadsheet(.csv) powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I want to do linking between two workitems with the linking -> Affects ("Affects" and "Affected by Linking") or Testedby ("Tested" by and "tests Linking") ??

I am using the approach as as shown in below post [TFS 2013 - Link Work Items via Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335878/tfs-2013-link-work-items-via-spreadsheet)

The problem is when I use ::TestedBy (code snippet is below)  I don't get the result but when I used :: Hierarchy or ::Dependency or ::Related, I am getting the result and script works fine. Hierarchy ,Dependency ,Related work fine as they System defined Link types but TestedBy and Affects type of linking are Process-template defined link types.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293527.aspx

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated please.

$hierarchyLink = $wis.WorkItemLinkTypes[[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.CoreLinkTypeReferenceNames]::TestedBy]

$link = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemLink($hierarchyLink.ReverseEnd, $map.Parent)
   $childWIT.WorkItemLinks.Add($link)

Comment: Got the solution :)                                                                             $hierarchyLink =  $wis.WorkItemLinkTypes["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy"]

Comment: This saved me hours of headache. Kudos!