# How can import TFS links between backlogs and tasks from excel

Tags: tfs

First i have export backlogs and related tasks from source TFS server to Excel
Then i have import all in an second TFS seerver

backlogs and tasks had been created correctly bat the liks between tasks and backlogs are not créated in the second server

It exists any way to import links beatwen backlogs and tasks ?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This is is about *programming* problems, not about problems of people somehow related to programming. Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand what this site is for. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it simply isn't related to a concrete programming problem and rather suited for the MS help desk.

Comment: This is a valid question and the correct place. This is a question related to how to do something in a development tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the links from Excel but you'll need to make sure you have the right query set up.

Create a query on the old server that brings back a TREE query showing PBIs/Bugs and their child Tasks.

Then create the same query on the new server which will come back blank but it is essential that it is also a TREE query.

Open it up in Excel and click the Add Child button to make sure you see the "Title 2" column.

Get all your columns in the same order as the export from the old server and then copy and paste.  Make sure you leave behind the old IDs (unless you want to create a custom field for it).

Hit publish and it will recreate the links between work items.

[image: Adding links from Excel]

Alternatively, if you want to do some scripting so Markus doesn't shout at you, then you can do something similar using PowerShell.
Check out:
[TFS 2013 - Link Work Items via Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335878/tfs-2013-link-work-items-via-spreadsheet/30347721)